# Istio + ExternalName + ElasticCache = timeout

Tags: istio, amazon-elasticache

I have an Istio setup within my cluster and connectivity to Redis is via an ExternalName to ElasticCache

After an hour of inactivity we get a disconnect:

```
aioredis        Connection has been closed by server, response: None
```

Can't seem to find exactly what is closing the connection after this time. AWS doesn't have a timeout set and the tcp connection should remain open.

Have added a DesinationRule attempting to increase tcp and HTTP timeout settings but not sure this is being utilised properly

Any pointers of where to look appreciated

Comment: What is your istio version? If I understand correctly redis is an external service, not injected with istio?